# SAVIOR NEEDED - How do I modify strategy?

Tags: loops, pine-script

I am trying to modify my pine script strategy to find the best set of inputs to use in order to achieve the best success rate for my indicator. I am wondering if there is any way to go through the time series more than once using a different set of inputs each time, so that I could save the values of the inputs that return the best success rate.

Is there any way to go through the time series starting at the first bar until the last bar using one set of inputs and then to go through the time series again from the first bar until the last bar with another set of inputs?

If this is possible, would it also be possible to have a variable that persists after going through the time series each time so that a best set of inputs could be found? For example, would it be possible to have code that resets every time that the end of the time series is reached for a set of inputs, but to have an array that will maintain its state, that could have its current values replaced by a set of inputs if they give  a better success rate than the previous sets of inputs.

I apologize if I did a poor job of phrasing this question. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried to help you..

Comment: A few tips to get good answers: Write a title that summarizes the issue, set tags that indicate the programming language you are using, ask 1 question and actually show what you have tried so far along with steps to reproduce the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question does not have a good title.  Remove the part in caps, and be specific with your summary. Choose a title that that distinguishes this question from other questions on the site.

Comment: If you want to programmatically check your strategy against the permutation of several input variables and their several possible values, you should check out https://tuned.com. In Pine there is no strategy generator that can backtest thousands of variations of your script (by generating those thousands of inputs). Tuned works on full Pine script compatibility but that is still in alpha stage.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.